# How can we give a free subscription period for a user who already subscribed? (For both Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

I hope I'm in the right place to ask this question. If not, please help to point out a better place to ask this.

I have a subscription-based app.

Now, I want to give a free period of subscription to a user who is already subscribing to my app.

For example, if the user started a monthly subscription (not a trial) on the 1st of July 2021. The original next billing date should be the 1st of August 2021.
But on the 15th of July, I give him a free month, then he shouldn't be billed on the 1st of August, instead, the next billing should become 1st of September.

Or if on the 15th of July, instead of giving 1 month free, I give him 2 weeks free, then the next billing cycle should be changed to 15th of August, and the consecutive billing cycle should be changed as well to reflect the 2 weeks period.

How can I do that with Google Play and Apple App Store?

I thought of the Promotion Codes. But it requires the user to unsubscribe and then enter the promotion code. A very tedious process.
I want to be able to give it without the user need to do anything else.
An example of App that does this is [ExpressVPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/), which adds a free-30-days for every successful referral. So if I can convince 2 of my friends to purchase a subscription, I will get 2x 30 days free on my subscription and my billing cycle will be pushed back accordingly. They also charge through the App Store / Google Play billing methods.

Answer (score -1):

Promotion codes is way to giving free subscription for a user and testing purpose In-App Purchase.And other way you can generate the token from back-end behalf of promotion codes.